# Possible to change the URL of SPO modern site collection URL?

Tags: site-collection, url, spo

Is it Possible to change the URL of SPO modern site collection URL?

I want to change the URL of site:

https://Company.microsoft.com/sites/SiteABC

To:

https://Company.microsoft.com/sites/SiteDEF

I know its possible to change the URL of subsite. Just want to know if its possible to change site collection URL?

Answer (score 1):

**The ability to rename a site is a preview feature**, so it’s not yet generally available within Office 365.

To rename a site, log on as a tenant global administrator, launch the Modern SharePoint Admin Center, go to Active Sites, and select the site you want to rename, and open the properties pane (Figure 1).

If the edit link is grayed out, it might be that the site is within the scope of a retention policy.

**Renaming a Site with PowerShell**

The latest version of the PowerShell module for SharePoint Online includes the Start-SPOSiteRename cmdlet.

More info at https://office365itpros.com/2019/05/02/sharepoint-online-rename-site-names/

Comment: I tried renaming a communication site collection URL using PowerShell and got the below error:

Start-SPOSiteRename : Error Code: -5,This site address can't be changed.It's not supported.

Comment: are you in the targeted release customer? I guess you would have to wait for the feature to become fully available.

Comment: You can find it in the cmdlet but till now it's still unusable.